# How to handle deduplication with CoreData and CloudKit?

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I can't find any updated tutorials on `CloudKit` with `CoreData` + `SwiftUI`. `CloudKit` does not support constraints then how do I merge duplicate records for my case?

I need to know what to do now that I had to disable `CoreData` constraints and the merge policy that I had in place. I have been following along with this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QGt0THnlwU

This is a simple code to take a form and save a todo to the viewContext and set the relationship to the category they selected. Which this now creates duplicate Categories which I do not want.

```
let newTodo = Todo(context: viewContext)
newTodo.title = title
newTodo.dueDate = dueDate
newTodo.relationship = Category(context: viewContext)
newTodo.relationship?.title = category
                    
try? self.viewContext.save()
dismiss()
```

Comment: See my comment to your previous question on this topic. This isn’t about CloudKit.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The comment was too vague, I'm still in need of a visible example in code to save the relationship. But I appreciate the pointer.

Comment: And don’t name your relationship “relationship”, name it category (and items). This will make your code clearer and will help you in the long run